# Where can I ask the question about only for mobile?

Tags: support, mobile

I need some software for my mobile and I know I can't ask it on SU because it's not related with PCs in some way.

So for mobiles, where can I ask questions? Does the Stack Exchange Network have any community for mobiles?

Comment: The title is quite misleading imo. It's merely about asking about [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's about Android phones, there' [Android Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com).

If it's about an iPhone, there's [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com)

There's an upcoming proposal about the [Windows Phone](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) phones and [a general one for Mobile phones](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11003/mobile-phones)

Comment: I've Java @Sathya.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any site for Java based feature phones.

Comment: Thanks @sathya for this nice info.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a site that can recommend which application you should use, [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Gadgets** was shut down, there's no Stack Exchange site for mobile gadgets.

The only 'exception' is Apple.SE which obviously allows questions about all Apple products, which include iPhones, iPods and iPads.